# C2DM Server with PHP 401 Error

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

I'm building my own C2DM application right now. I first started with a small Android application to test the push feature. And it works if I just call the curl command with the correct settings in my shell.

Now for the server part I wanted to use PHP but as it seems I'm doing something wrong as I always get a 401 error message when I try to send a message to the client. First of all the code consists of two parts. The first curl request asks for the server token. This works I get a real response from google with a working token!

The second curl request ends up with a 401 error message. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
  $post_params = array ( "Email" => $MY_GOOGLE_ACC, "Passwd" => $MY_GOOGLE_PWD, "accountType"=>"GOOGLE", "source=" . $MY_GOOGLE_SRC, "service=ac2dm" ); 

  $first = true;
  $data_msg = "";

  foreach ($post_params as $key => $value) { 
    if ($first)
      $first = false;
    else
      $data_msg .= "&";

    $data_msg .= urlencode($key) ."=". urlencode($value); 
  }

  $x = curl_init("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"); 

  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_msg); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $data = curl_exec($x); 
  curl_close($x); 
  $response = $data;

  $authKey = trim(substr($response, 4+strpos($response, "SID=")));

  echo $authKey;
  $collapse_key = 'something';

  $post_params = array ( "registration_id" => $DEVICE_TOKEN, "collapse_key" => $collapse_key, "data.payload"=>"cakephp" ); 

  $first = true;
  $data_msg = "";

  foreach ($post_params as $key => $value) { 
    if ($first)
      $first = false;
    else
      $data_msg .= "&";

    $data_msg .= urlencode($key) ."=". urlencode($value); 
  }

  $size=strlen($data_msg); 


  $x = curl_init("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send"); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length:'. $size, 'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authKey)); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_msg); 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $data = curl_exec($x); 
  curl_close($x); 
  $response = $data;
```

Comment: ok. I have no clue why, but nothing works anymore. even with my curl examples i always get a 401 error. Right now if I try to auth myself I get a SID, LSID and Auth Token back. I'm not really sure if this was the same yesterday? I think yesterday I only got 1 token back. But I have to check this again later.
What changed maybe is that I switched computers. I'm not on the same computer anymore as I tried yesterday when everything worked. Does this maybe have to do something with this?

Comment: Hi nino! I just copy the code you posted upstair,and I also get the same 401 problem.So...could you tell me how do you fix this problem,or could you post your worked code to me?Thanks for helping!yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of key'd array use with curl.  This is pretty much the exact code I have working (with minor changes for clarity).

```
$headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authcode);
$data = array(
    'registration_id' => $device_registration_id,
    'collapse_key' => 'ck_' . $device_id,
    'data.arg' => 'arrrrghhh'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
if($headers) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
```

$authcode is the SID returned by ClientLogin.  $device_registration_id is the registration ID that the client app on the phone gave us when we did the C2DM_REGISTER.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work either. I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with my account now... 
May I ask you how often you refresh your auth token? Maybe I got banned for trying to often?
I get an SID, LSID and Auth Token back. Do you only use the SID token?

Comment: Ok, my code works now (yours, and mine actually), but only with the code I first generated with the shell curl tool. There is one interesting thing about it. The first code I got, only had one SID in it. When I try to recreate a token i get back a SID, LSID and Auth token, which don't work for authentification.
Now, can you maybe answer me this question. How often does one have to recreate the auth token? How did you handle this (maybe I can only change it, when the old one expires?)

Comment: -Hi nino! I just copy the code you posted upstair,and I also get the same 401 problem.So...could you tell me how do you fix this problem,or  could you post your worked code to me?Thanks for helping!yours.

Comment: I think this is a bigger issue than we first realised.  I have now just used my service with another google account and I too get the 401 error.  However if I use my normal Google account, it works.  The only difference that I know is that the account that works is the account that i use in the sender_id field.  If I use another account it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to register your app [here](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup). I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what's going on here, but here's a few difference I noticed from my application server that works fine.

In your curl_setopt call for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER there is no space between the content length and the size.  This 'shouldn't cause a problem, but I've seen webservers get tempremental over stupid stuff like that before.

Also, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is a string whereas I send mine as a key'd array.

Other than that I looks the same as my working code.

Comment: I added a space in between content length and the size and still nothing.

Could you show me an example on how to use a key'd array with CURL?